# foursquare code error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, foursquare

I have this project and I know the question is dumb, but I really can't fix it.
I'd really appreaciate it if someone can help me :)

```
import requests
import json

payload = {}
headers = {}
ll1 = 18.036442,42.492103
ll2 = 18.036808,42.117917
ll3 = 18.458814,42.485903
ll4 = 18.453989,42.115408


def make_request(payload, headers, ll1, ll2, ll3, ll4):

url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=VFFCWVM5UPLGNOS3IAQHQB5LLZBIRYZTGUYW40JHKSEMM0BR" \
      "&client_secret=PCF41XEGDNVIZSZT5ULESYGZUTW02TVYKX5IOAEAAMF5GYP1&v=20210927&token" \
      "=AEOYTHHSPVCSNNBFRT0RCH55KVRXJ1EH2XDSXPIWEWJEMEPG&ll=" +ll1+ +ll2 +ll3 +ll4+ \
      "&intent=browse&radius=10000 "
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
return response.text


data = make_request(payload, headers, ll1, ll2, ll3, ll4)

print (data)
```

the error I get is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hessa/Desktop/main01.py", line 22, in <module>
    data = make_request(payload, headers, ll1, ll2, ll3, ll4)
  File "/Users/hessa/Desktop/main01.py", line 14, in make_request
    url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=VFFCWVM5UPLGNOS3IAQHQB5LLZBIRYZTGUYW40JHKSEMM0BR" \
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

Comment: What do you want the resulting URL to look like? As the error clearly says you can't concatenate tuples to strings, but even if converted to strings `=18.036442,42.49210318.036808,42117917...` is probably not what you want.  I'd expect a delimiter of some kind between the pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```py
import requests
import json

payload = {}
headers = {}
ll1 = "18.036442,42.492103"
ll2 = "18.036808,42.117917"
ll3 = "18.458814,42.485903"
ll4 = "18.453989,42.115408"


def make_request(payload, headers, ll1):
    url = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=VFFCWVM5UPLGNOS3IAQHQB5LLZBIRYZTGUYW40JHKSEMM0BR" \
    "&client_secret=PCF41XEGDNVIZSZT5ULESYGZUTW02TVYKX5IOAEAAMF5GYP1&v=20210927&token" \
    "=AEOYTHHSPVCSNNBFRT0RCH55KVRXJ1EH2XDSXPIWEWJEMEPG&ll=" + ll1 + \
    "&intent=browse&radius=10000"
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.text


data = make_request(payload, headers, ll1)
data = make_request(payload, headers, ll2)
data = make_request(payload, headers, ll3)
data = make_request(payload, headers, ll4)

print (data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I got this now:

`{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"param_error","errorDetail":"ll must be of the form XX.XX,YY.YY (received 18.036442,42.49210318.036808,42.11791718.458814,42.48590318.453989,42.115408)","requestId":"617e4f51444f741c21fe689e"},"response":{}}`

Comment: Updated the answer. You need to send the request with only 1 coordinates at a time

Answer (score 0):

pass variables as string

```
ll1 = '18.036442,42.492103'
ll2 = '18.036808,42.117917'
ll3 = '18.458814,42.485903'
ll4 = '18.453989,42.115408'
```

Comment: I fixed it and I got this :
_______

`{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"param_error","errorDetail":"ll must be of the form XX.XX,YY.YY (received 18.036442,42.49210318.036808,42.11791718.458814,42.48590318.453989,42.115408)","requestId":"617e4e5a237a1756c83a94de"},"response":{}}`